# Transition probability matrix of a markov chain $A^{(\infty)}$

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

> The transition probability matrix of a Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ on state
> space $\{1,2\}$ is
> $A=\begin{pmatrix}1-\alpha&\alpha\\\beta&1-\beta\end{pmatrix}$, where
> $0<\alpha,\beta<1$.
>
> 1. Determine $A^{(\infty)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^{(n)}$
> 2. Find the probabilities as $n\rightarrow\infty$:
>    (i) $\Pr(X_n=2,X_{n+1}=1|X_1=1)$; (ii) $\Pr(X_{n-1}=2|X_n=1)$.

I found $A^{(2)}$ to be $\begin{pmatrix}(1-\alpha)^2+(1-\alpha)\alpha&(1-\alpha)\alpha+\alpha(1-\beta)\\
\beta(1-\alpha)&\beta\alpha+(1-\beta)^2\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^{(3)}=\begin{pmatrix}(1-\alpha)^3+(1-\alpha)^2\alpha+(1-\alpha)\alpha^2+\alpha^2(1-\beta)&\alpha(1-\alpha)^2+(1-\alpha)\alpha^2+\beta(1-\alpha)\alpha+\alpha(1-\beta)\beta\\
\beta(1-\alpha)^2+\beta^2\alpha+\beta(1-\beta)^2&\beta(1-\alpha)\alpha+\beta\alpha(1-\beta)+(1-\beta)^3\end{pmatrix}$. It is not obvious to me what this is converging to. For $\alpha=1/4,\beta=1/3$, it seems to converge to $$\begin{pmatrix}0.5714286&0.4285714\\0.5714286&0.4285714\end{pmatrix}$$

based on $1000$ iterations, so definitely not $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $A^{(\infty)}$ you should either diagonalize $A$ or just find the invariant distribution. If you go the latter way, $A^{(\infty)}$ will just have all its rows given by the invariant distribution since the chain is ergodic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused, is $A^{(n)}$ just $AAA...A$ n times multiplied together? The way I calculated $A^{(2)}$ and $A^{(3)}$, it is not simply $AA$ or $AAA$.

Comment: Never mind lol! I made a mistake in the chaining, it is true that $A^{(n)}=A^n$. The diagonalization worked. Ty!